# KendoUI DateTimePicker format UTC date integrating with Angular model

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, formatdatetime

I have this in my html page

```
<input id="date" ng-model="config.selectedData.date" />
```

And this in my controller

```
$timeout(function () {
$("#date").kendoDateTimePicker({
    format: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mmtt"
});
if ($("#" + key).data("kendoDateTimePicker") != undefined)
    $("#" + key).data("kendoDateTimePicker").readonly();
}, 50);
```

My model $scope.config.selectedData.date = "0000-12-31T22:00:00.000Z"

I want to see something like : ' 1/1/0000 00:00 '

But i see: 'Mon Jan 01    1 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)'

Answer (score 0):

For this, Please use this library.

http://momentjs.com/